# Spring Integration Java DSL - How to invoke int-http:outbound-gateway?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-integration, dsl

I have a piece in the flow where a ReST API call is made:

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                           reply-channel="logger"
                           url="${api.base.uri}/data"
                           http-method="PUT"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"
                             logger-name="logger"
                             expression="payload"
                             level="INFO"/>
```

I'm trying to replicate this using Java DSL but could not find adequate documentation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i did not understand your doubt,  convert to Java DSL? you mean Domain Specific Languages?

Comment: @RafaelZeffa - yep, refer this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference

Comment: thank you.. i did't know this project!

Comment: Guys, give me a couple minutes to prepare an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, Spring Integration Java DSL doesn't provide the Namespace Factory for HTTP, yet.

Anyway we can go ahead and do that using its generic components:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler logger() {
        LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
        loggingHandler.setLoggerName("logger");
        // This is redundant because the default expression is exactly "payload"
        // loggingHandler.setExpression("payload");
        return loggingHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler httpGateway(@Value("${api.base.uri}/data") URI uri) {
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpHandler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(uri);
        httpHandler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
        httpHandler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        return httpHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpFlow(MessageHandler httpGateway) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChannel")
                .handle(httpGateway)
                .handle(logger())
                .get();
    }
```

From other side the mentioned documentation demonstrate the sample exactly for the `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway`...

**UPDATE**

By the way: feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) ticket for adding HTTP support to the Java DSL.

Comment: Thanks for this, works perfectly. I will raise a JIRA ticket :) 
Before posting the question, I did try using HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler (with reference to the documented usage of HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway) .. however, I couldn't get a clear understanding of how to use it. Is there a good documentation of various namespace resolution/java based implementation of integration components/channels?  So that I can use them along with DSL (in case DSL does not support them).

Comment: Yeah... It's a bit tricky: 1) each module has its own `AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler`, e.g. `HttpNamespaceHandler`. 2) each namespace component (xml tag) has its own parser, e.g. `HttpOutboundGatewayParser`. 3) each parser produces one or more beans for the application context, e.g. `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`.  I think we will do in the next release some "hard" work to mention in the XSD for which target class is the perticular XML tag.

Comment: Thanks again, this is really helpful info. Yes, It would be great if that information could be included in the XSD.

Comment: I see that the ticket is resolved. Is there a place where I can see how to use the new [HTTP support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/http) in the Java DSL? I can't find unit/integration tests or any documentation.

Comment: Does that work for you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/http/HttpTests.java ? BTW, feel free to ask any additional questions but in the separate SO threads!