# Spring Integration Java DSL: How to loop the paged Rest service?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to loop the paged Rest service with the Java DSL `Http.outboundGateway`method?

The rest URL is for example

```
http://localhost:8080/people?page=3
```

and it returns for example

```
"content": [
    {"name": "Mike",
     "city": "MyCity"
    },
    {"name": "Peter",
     "city": "MyCity"
    },
    ...
 ]
"pageable": {
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "pageSize": 20,
    "pageNumber": 3,
    "offset": 60,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
},
"last": false,
"totalElements": 250,
"totalPages": 13,
"first": false,
"sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
},
"number": 3,
"numberOfElements": 20,
"size": 20
}
```

where the variable `totalPages` tells the total pages amount.

So if the implementation

```
        integrationFlowBuilder
          .handle(Http
            .outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/people?page=3")
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .expectedResponseType(String.class))
```

access one page, how to loop all the pages?

Comment: Please add some more information.

Comment: added earlier more information

Comment: You can check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825508/spring-integration-java-dsl-how-to-invoke-int-httpoutbound-gateway

Comment: I think your link don't answer my question. It answers how to do the REST call. I want to loop multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is like wrapping the call to this `Http.outboundGateway()` with the `@MessagingGateway` and provide a page number as an argument:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface HttpPagingGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "httpPagingGatewayChannel")
    String getPage(int page);

}
```

Then you get a JSON as a result, where you can convert it into some domain model or just perform a `JsonPathUtils.evaluate()` (based on [json-path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)) to get the value of the `last` attribute to be sure that you need to call that `getPage()` for the `page++` or not.

The `page` argument is going to be a `payload` of the message to send and that can be used as an `uriVariable`:

```
.handle(Http
        .outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/people?page={page}")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .uriVariable("page", Message::getPayload)
        .expectedResponseType(String.class))
```

Of course, we can do something similar with Spring Integration, but there are going to be involved `filter`, `router` and some other components.

**UPDATE**

First of all I would suggest you to create a domain model (some Java Bean), let's say `PersonPageResult`, to represent that JSON response and this type to the `expectedResponseType(PersonPageResult.class)` property of the `Http.outboundGateway()`. The `RestTemplate` together with the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` out-of-the-box will do the trick for you to return such an object as a reply for the downstream processing.

Then, as I said before, looping would be better done from some Java code, which you could wrap to the service activator call. For this purpose you should daclare a gateway like this:

```
public interface HttpPagingGateway {

    PersonPageResult getPage(int page);

}
```

Pay attention: no annotations at all. The trick is done via `IntegrationFlow`:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpGatewayFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(HttpPagingGateway.class)
                  .handle(Http
                       .outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/people?page={page}")
                       .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                       .uriVariable("page", Message::getPayload)
                       .expectedResponseType(PersonPageResult.class))  
}
```

See `IntegrationFlows.from(Class<?> aClass)` JavaDocs.

Such a `HttpPagingGateway` can be injected into some service with hard looping logic:

```
int page = 1;
boolean last = false;
while(!last) {
  PersonPageResult result = this.httpPagingGateway.getPage(page++);
  last = result.getLast();
  List<Person> persons = result.getPersons();
  // Process persons
}
```

For processing those `persons` I would suggest to have separate `IntegrationFlow`, which may start from the gateway as well or you can just send a `Message<List<Person>>` to its input channel.

This way you will separate concerns about paging and processing and will have a simple loop logic in some POJO method.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do this, but had difficulties and looked also a lot of examples like excellent https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial. Could you please write more implementation? How the looping works etc. How to call the `httpPagingGatewayChannel` from my `integrationFlowBuilder` and pass the initial page number 1.

Comment: Could you please also tell and give some implementation hints how to continue processing of the results. There will be multiple `HTTP GETs` for the different pages and I want to process the data. One page request returns the `JSON`, which contains array of the people (Mike, Peter etc). I want to process the each person of the each page in my `integrationFlowBuilder`.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer. The policy here on SO dictates us do not code for requestors. So, you need to do final hard work yourself.

Comment: Thanks really much. It seems this is a way that works.